# Adding a toolbar to INAppStoreWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstoolbar

I'm trying to add a toolbar to INAppStoreWindow.

It has this property:

```
/** The title bar view itself. Add subviews to this view that you want to show in
 the title bar (e.g. buttons, a toolbar, etc.). This view can also be set if 
you want to use a different styled title bar aside from the default one 
(textured, etc.). **/

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSView *titleBarView;
```

I have a toolbar created, and linked to an outlet in my code, but how can I add it as a subview if it has a class of NSToolbar, when it requires a NSView?

This throws an exception:    `[aWindow.titleBarView addSubview:toolbar];`

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) weasels that `titleBarView` between the window's widgets and the content view:

**INAppStoreWindow.m:**

```
- (void)setTitleBarView:(NSView *)newTitleBarView
{
if ((_titleBarView != newTitleBarView) && newTitleBarView)  {
    [_titleBarView removeFromSuperview];
    [_titleBarView release];
    _titleBarView = [newTitleBarView retain];

    // Configure the view properties and add it as a subview of the theme frame
    NSView *contentView = [self contentView];
    NSView *themeFrame = [contentView superview];
    NSView *firstSubview = [[themeFrame subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [_titleBarView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewWidthSizable)];
    [self _recalculateFrameForTitleBarView];
    [themeFrame addSubview:_titleBarView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:firstSubview];
    [self _layoutTrafficLightsAndContent];
    [self display];
    }
}
```

`NSToolbar` isn't an `NSView` subclass, it's meant to work in conjunction with the window itself, which is obscured by the `titleBarView`. Just for kicks, set alphas of the gradient colors in `INAppStoreWindow.m` and run the app; you'll can see the "real" window is still there underneath.

If you're set on using `INAppStoreWindow`, your best bet would probably be to use your own custom view with buttons to fake a toolbar and adding that as a subview of the `titleBarView`. Of course, in that case you'll have to do all the layout yourself.

Comment: Perfect! Just one more thing, how would I centre the subview, and get it to remain in the centre even when the window changes size?

Comment: `INAppStoreWindow` does that work in  `-(void)_layoutTrafficLightsAndContent`, I'd subclass it and reset your subview's bounds there.